# UDEV Shell script permissions issue

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, bash, udev

I have a shell script called media_change.sh it is being run by a udev role on status change of a device.

UDEV

```
ACTION=="change", ATTRS{idVendor}=="057b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="0000", ENV{DISK_MEDIA_CHANGE}=="1", RUN+="/home/pi/media_change.sh $env{DEVNAME}"
```

media_change.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
exec >> /home/pi/mount.log 2>&1

echo "$(date) Start."
echo "$(date) Media change detected on device $1"
device=${1##*/}
echo $(whoami)

lsblk | grep $device

if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "$(date) Device exists on machine."
    echo "$(date) Mounting device $1 to /mnt/floppy."
    sudo -u pi sh /home/pi/test.sh
else
    echo "$(date) Device does not exist on machine."
fi
echo "$(date) End."
```

This executes another shell script called test.sh that just runs a nodejs script for me

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $(whoami)
cd /home/pi/SpotifyDisk-node && node player.js file
```

If I run media_change.sh as pi the script runs as expected

```
➜  ~ ./media_change.sh
Fri  6 Mar 13:57:23 GMT 2020 Start.
Fri  6 Mar 13:57:23 GMT 2020 Media change detected on device
pi
sda           8:0    1  1.4M  0 disk /mnt/floppy
Fri  6 Mar 13:57:23 GMT 2020 Device exists on machine.
Fri  6 Mar 13:57:23 GMT 2020 Mounting device  to /mnt/floppy.
pi
DiskPlayer Not found in device list
Fri  6 Mar 13:57:27 GMT 2020 End.
```

If I run media_change.sh sudo the script also runs as expected -

```
Fri  6 Mar 13:57:50 GMT 2020 Start.
Fri  6 Mar 13:57:50 GMT 2020 Media change detected on device
root
sda           8:0    1  1.4M  0 disk /mnt/floppy
Fri  6 Mar 13:57:50 GMT 2020 Device exists on machine.
Fri  6 Mar 13:57:50 GMT 2020 Mounting device  to /mnt/floppy.
pi
DiskPlayer Not found in device list
Fri  6 Mar 13:57:54 GMT 2020 End.
```

But when the script runs on the change of device via UDEV it gives the following error -

```
Fri Mar  6 14:02:27 GMT 2020 Start.
Fri Mar  6 14:02:27 GMT 2020 Media change detected on device /dev/sda
root
sda           8:0    1  1.4M  0 disk /mnt/floppy
Fri Mar  6 14:02:27 GMT 2020 Device exists on machine.
Fri Mar  6 14:02:27 GMT 2020 Mounting device /dev/sda to /mnt/floppy.
sudo: unable to resolve host DiskPlayer: Temporary failure in name resolution
pi


#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: SetPermissions(buffer, allocated, PageAllocator::kReadExecute).
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0x7ec46800Illegal instruction
Fri Mar  6 14:02:27 GMT 2020 End.
```

Comment: Environments perhaps different. What does player.js look like?

Comment: Same environment, I even created a simple test.js that just console.log('test') but that gives me the same error, again, works fine when executed via pi or sudo, just doesn't work from the UDEV rule

Comment: what happens if you run `./media_change.sh /dev/sda`?

Comment: similar idea to https://www.dinofizzotti.com/blog/2020-02-05-diskplayer-using-3.5-floppy-disks-to-play-albums-on-spotify/ only with thumb drives?

Comment: I used that as the base, still using floppy disks, but I wanted to extend it and don't know go, so rewrote it into nodejs, but can't get the idea role to run my new player file..

Comment: sounds like a programming error in your player.js file then. In the other cases when you said the script runs as expected, you heard audio?

Comment: Yep, everything works fine, only fails when run via udev, I have actually taken a different approach and abandoned this idea as it isn't going to work.

Answer (score 0):

If your script is looking to connect using a hostname of 'DiskPlayer' then perhaps the issue is with your hosts file.  See https://askubuntu.com/questions/466122/why-i-got-unable-to-resolve-host-when-i-do-sudo.

If that's not the issue, do you get the same error if you remove test.sh and directly invoke node?

`cd /home/pi/SpotifyDisk-node`

`sudo -u pi node player.js file`

.

Comment: Hi, Yes I get the same error when directly invoking node, but again only when running via UDEV fine with pi/sudo

Comment: Hmm.  Have you tried passing the current env to test.sh by doing this?

sudo -E -u pi sh /home/pi/test.sh